# How to show graphs are homeomorphic (or not)

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

[image: The graphs are here]

Hi,

I am trying to figure out which of these are homeomorphic (topologically equivalent)

I know that number of cut points, and numver of vertices (where degree is ont 2) are topological invariants

But I am struggling to apply the criterion to this example

Help very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the graphs are quite unique: Only $\Gamma$ is homeomorphic to an interval $[0,1]$, only $O$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$, only $K$ has a degree 4 vertex, only Ж has a degree 6 vertex.

Б and $\Phi$ are tho only ones with exactly one leaf, but they differ in number of degree 3 vertices.

Among the remaining(!), $\forall$ is the only with two leaves, $8$ is the only without leaves, $\exists$ the only with three leaves, $H$ th eonly with four leaves.

hence no thwo are homeomorhic.

Comment: Doesn't $Φ$ (like $K$) have a degree $4$ vertex?

Comment: hi, what is a leaf? also, why is Γ homeomophic to [0,1], because it can be stretched to a segment of a line? thanks